# What's the equivalent of jQuery.when() in angular

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, promise, jquery-deferred

In jQuery we can do

`$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  ...
});`

What's the equivalent in angular? I really need to wait for all ajax calls finish then do stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$q.all` to handle multiple promises. Also, use $http to make the calls, that's more angular.

Here is a nice tutorial:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent would be:

```
$q.all([$http.get('/page1.php'),$http.get('/page2.php')]).then(function(values){
   var a1 = values[0];
   var a2 = values[1];
   ... 
});
```

[AngularJS Documentation for $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)