# What's the equivalent of jQuery.when() in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, promise, fs

I asked [whats the equivalent of jquery when in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335960/whats-the-equivalent-of-jquery-when-in-angular) and now I want to do similar thing in node. I need to something like this:

`when(fs.readFile('file1'), fs.readFile('file2'))
    .done(function( a1, a2 ) {
       ... // do stuff
    });`

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need node 0.11.13 or higher for this to work or to use a library but that would be `Promise.all`:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird"); // Imports the Bluebird promise library in 
                                   // new versions of node this is optional

Promise.promisifyAll(fs); // this is required if using Bluebird, you'll have to 
                          // do this manually with native promises.
Promise.all([fs.readFileAsync('file1'), fs.readFileAsync('file2')])
.spread(function( a1, a2 ) {
   ... // do stuff
});
```

As for how to convert a callback API to promises - see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny right, but in new versions of node promises _ship as a part of Node_ since they're accepted into the new JavaScript standard. In node 0.12 promises will work out of the box. Bluebird in particular works on Netscape 7, so Node 0.8 isn't really a challenge :)

Comment: Promises work in any node.js vesion, or at least since `0.8.x`.

Comment: How did our comments get inverted :S?

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment.